# Confirm FFC pinout for forward and reverse direction

Tags: pinout, fpc, ffc

The first timer is using FFC so I would like to know about the pinout of the FFC forward and reverse cable. Below is an image from eBay showing both types; I have annotated pin1.

Is my understanding of forward and reverse of pin1 correct in each case?

[image: Annotated FFC Cable from eBay]

Answer (score 1):

With many of these FFC cables, there usually isn't a defined pin by the manufacturer it is defined by the designer on the schematic.

So you could go with the picture and have that be pin1.

Comment: Understood but let's assume that pin1 is given by the MFR on the left side of the image. Would pin1 match those on the right? Effectively is the signal correctly routed in the cables as per my understanding?

Comment: What does the drawing say?

Answer (score 1):

The FFC socket is numbered. The cable is not. So, go by the numbering of the FFC socket.

---

Assuming two identical sockets (e.g., both with bottom contacts), both mounted on top of PCBs, then:

The "reverse cable" does *not* reverse the circuits: it connects pin 1 of one socket to pin 1 of the other socket, pin 2 to pin 2, and so forth.

The "Forward" cable *does* reverse the circuits: it connects pin 1 of one socket to pin 20 of the other socket, pin 2 to pin 19, and so forth.

---

However, if the two sockets are different  (i.e., one has top contacts, the other has bottom contacts), or identical sockets are mounted on different sides of the PCB (one on top, one on the bottom), then:

The "reverse cable" *does* reverse the circuits: it connects pin 1 of one socket to pin 20 of the other socket, pin 2 to pin 19, and so forth.

The "Forward" cable does *not* reverse the circuits: it connects pin 1 of one socket to pin 1 of the other socket, pin 2 to pin 2, and so forth.

(You have to visualize in 3 dimensions to figure it out.)